# Is it good idea to use useEffect in all components to prevent unwanted re-renders in components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My situation is,

If i have a parent component that should re-render for a certain reason(change in **state** or **props**), and a child component that has no change in its **state** or **props**, or if the child is just a representational component  with no state or props

In this situation, parent component will be re-rendered and also the child will be re-rendered by the parent.

So, is it a good idea to use an empty `useEffect` in that child component to prevent its re-render??

Comment: Why would you want to prevent it?

Comment: you can use `React.memo()` if your component renders the same result given the same props, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: @zb22 from that very page, *This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.*

Comment: @Yatrix to prevent unwanted rerender, and add to performance?

Comment: @CodeEagle and *what* makes it unwanted? Is your app rendering so many times that it's hindering usability?

Comment: @Yatrix no but i am talking about performance improvement, by preventing child components to rerender when parent rerender, why i need to rerender a component if its state and props didn't change, isn't that waste of resources??

Comment: @Yatrix, performance optimization of not rendering if nothing was changed regarding to the props, this is what the user asks for as I see here.

Comment: @CodeEagle "no". There's your answer. Let React do React stuff and don't address problems the app doesn't have. If your app is performing poorly, _then_ optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be wary of trying to optimize renders too much. You can look into [Pure Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), but in general renders are very cheap since they don't update the DOM if it's not needed (DOM changes, particularly creaing new nodes, are more expensive).

Unless you have a strong reason to start optimizing, it's better to not think about renders too much. Also, bear in mind that functions passed to a child component do change when the parent re-renders, in this case you do want the child re-render to happen:

```js
function ParentComponent() {
  
  const onClickChild = () => console.log("child clicked");

  return <ChildComponent onClick={onClickChild} />
  // ☝️ re-render of parent causes the 'onClick' prop to change:
}
```

If you want to dive deeper, you may want to look into [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), but again, child renders don't usually hurt performance.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good answer, so triggering a render tree itself is not a big issue for performance,, the issue is exactly in re-painting, so if no change in state or props, a new render tree will be created but not repainted?

Comment: New render trees are created if I am not mistaken, but even if props or state change, it doesn't mean the DOM gets changed -- the DOM only gets changed if the reconciliation, aka React's "diffing" algorithm detects a need to repaint. For example, if you return a constant element, such as `return <div>Hello</div>`, React won't rerender the component even if props/state change.